# How to call cms static block in footer.phtml in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

```
How to call CMS static block in footer.phtml in Magento? kindly help me. for this
```

i tried to below code but not working

getLayout()createBlock('cms/block')setBlockId('footer')toHtml(); ?>

Answer (score 1):

Hi tried to this may be help.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('footer')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call CMS block like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('footer')->toHtml() ?>
```